# How do I run an integer validation rule against a Number(x, 0) field?

Tags: validation, custom-field

I see in the [Number documentation](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/custom_field_types.htm) that Salesforce does some rounding, but I'm observing truncation.  In the [Number Validation Rules from Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8pNv.png) there is a *Number Must Be an Integer* validation rule that specifies that the following can be used to validate that a field is an integer.

```
FLOOR( My_Integer__c) <> My_Integer__c
```

I have a field defined as Number(4,0) and I have that validation rule, but the rule is not firing when a value that is not an integer is entered.  Instead it truncates the decimal part.

For example, if I enter in 1.75 it will silently change the value to a 1, without a validation failure.

I would rather have the error message displayed to the user than silently changing the number that was input, but I don't want to change the actual data type from Number(4,0).

For good measure, here's the validation rule:
[image: Validation Rule for Integer]

I did see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3455/154 which seems closely related; however, Java's Integer.parseInt (at least in Java 1.6.0_25) throws a NumberFormatException for non Integer values (e.g, "1.75").

I am open to other possibilities, but would rather not have to code something.

The field is in a managed package and I cannot change its definition from Number(4,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined the field with zero decimal places then you do not need that validation rule; you have defined the field to be an integer. I am surprised that Salesforce just silently truncates the input, though, as I would have expected a system error message.

Comment: Thanks.  The silent part is what is frustrating.  If the field weren't in a managed package I could change its definition and use the validation rule.